# XHR_PROP_IGNORE_CERT_ERRORS not working

Tags: ssl, windows-store-apps, uwp, windows-10-universal, self-signed

- It's a Windows Store App written in c++.
- OS is Windows 10 Pro.
- IDE is VS Express 2015 for Windows 10

I've been using IXMLHTTPRequest3 to make https request to server with a self signed certificate.

As the certificate is self signed, I use "**SetProperty(XHR_PROP_IGNORE_CERT_ERRORS, XHR_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS);**" to ignore certificate error.

However, it doesn't work, each time it will return error: ***Security certificate required to access this resource is invalid***.

Is there any additional settings I need to do?

Thanks.